# Is it true that $\frac {a}{a+b}+\frac {b}{b+c}+\frac {c}{c+a}\geq \frac32$ if $a+b+c=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, polynomials, fractions, rearrangement-inequality

Is it possible to prove that $ \dfrac {a}{a+b}+\dfrac {b}{b+c}+\dfrac {c}{c+a}\geq \dfrac {3}{2}$, if $ a+b+c=1, a,b,c>0$?

Comment: Actually the problem was that: if a,b,c are real, positive numbers,a+b+c=1 prove that $\dfrac {a^{2}+b}{b+c}+\dfrac {b^{2}+c}{c+a}+\dfrac {c^{2}+a}{a+b}\geq 2$

Answer (score 2):

I think it's wrong.

Try $c\rightarrow0^+$.

We obtain $$\frac{a}{a+b}\geq\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$a\geq b$$ and you can get a counterexample with $a<b$.

Also, we can see it for $a\rightarrow0^+$: we obtain $0\geq\frac{1}{2}.$

By the way, your second problem is true.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+b}{b+c}\geq2$$ or
 $$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b)(a+b)(a+c)\geq2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b)(a^2+ab+ac+bc)\geq2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b)(a+bc)\geq2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3+\frac{1}{3}abc+ab+a^2b\right)\geq2\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c+\frac{2}{3}abc\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a^3+\frac{1}{3}abc+a^2b+a^2c+abc+a^2b\right)\geq2\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c+\frac{2}{3}abc\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2c)\geq0,$$ which is true by Rearrangement.

Comment: +1 I suspect @gimusi was correct and the OP missstated Nesbitt's inequality.

Comment: Yes, it's not Nesbitt.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is right, computing the left hand side minus the right hand side we obtain $$1/2\,{\frac { \left( b-c \right)  \left( a-c \right)  \left( a-b
 \right) }{ \left( a+b \right)  \left( b+c \right)  \left( c+a
 \right) }}
\geq 0$$